# Doubt in Hall's theorem in Graph theory

Tags: graph-theory

> A bipartite graph $ G(X \cup Y, E)$ has a matching that saturates X iff $|S| \leq |N(S)| \forall S \subseteq X$ , $N(S) $ is neighbour vertex set of S

I understood the meaning of this. **But why are we checking all the subsets of  X. Instead why can we just see on X only** ie., $|X| \leq |N(X)| $as we need at least X counter vertices as neighbours in Y for all vertices in X to be included in matching. I am a beginner. Please elaborate as I am slowly understanding.

Comment: Suppose that some vertex $v$ of $X$ is isolated.  It doesn't matter how large $N(X)$ is; no matching will ever cover $v$.

Comment: You don't have yo check ***all*** the subsets, just the nonempty subsets.The inequality holds automatically if $S$ is empty.

Comment: @saulspatz Sir if some vertex v of X is isolated, then X will not be saturated right? My doubt is we need to check where all vertices of X has different counter vertices in Y. In that case we need see couter part of X. But here in text book why he is considering the checking process on any subset of X.

Comment: @saulspatz what if there is some isolated vertex in X but all neighbors of X \ {v} are more than neighbours of X? halls theorem satisfies but yet X vertices are not matched as v is isolated

Comment: @bof what is intuition behind checking on all subsets of X? what comes in my mind is to check N(X)

Comment: @saulspatz sir is it to escape that isolated vertex condition, we need to check all subsets of X? pls correct me if i am thinking wrongly

Comment: The intuition is that, if $|S|\gt|N(S)|$ for some $S\subseteq X$, then the matching is impossible. Consider this example: $X=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, $Y=\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}$, $E=\{x_1y_1,x_2y_1,x_3y_1,x_3y_2,x_3y_3\}$. The condition $|S|\le|N(S)|$ is satisfied for every $S\subseteq X$ except $S=\{x_1,x_2\}$. Do you see a matching?

Comment: @bof got it ...tq